# Windows Installation taking forever

Tags: windows-7, installation

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on a machine that was running Win7 perfectly until I decided to format and reinstall. I've tried a bootable USB and a DVD, but I'm getting the same result, I'm talking around 6-8 hours at the "Expanding Windows Files", very slow response before, and during the initial "Please setup username" section, it's just as slow. I've replaced the hard drive and taken out all but one of the ram sticks.. what could be the issue? It's a standard HP Pavilion, nothing too fancy, but please note, Win7 was running flawlessly until I reinstalled it (bought it from a friend so wanted a clean install).

Comment: This sort of behavior normally points to an issue with the HDD.

Comment: That's what I thought initially until I put a HDD in from my fully functional secondary computer, on which I would have run disk diagnostics within the last month at least. Same issue, it's horribly slow even before it starts writing to disk (at the very first screen you see when you start the installation)

Answer (score 1):

My PC was also seemingly stuck at the expanding windows files. I took the dvd out and cleaned it and it started working really fast. So I suggest if you have this problem to first try cleaning the dvd, and if that doesnt work try reburning it i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Seems people have reported this over at Microsoft. Couple different options you can try. Most involve some form of BIOS disable. You can work your way through the options and see what works for you. Find it  [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2aec8bd7-c05d-4de0-a31a-92458c8c3bf7/installation-extremely-slow-hangs-during-expanding-windows-files?forum=w7itproinstall).

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the appropriate SATA Driver?  Also, you can prepare and diagnose the volume of the drive using GPARTED and just Google to download..  It is about ~100MB Download ISO file..  Cool stuff.

Comment: Okay, I'll check that out, lets see how it goes, thanks

Comment: @Leptonator - A SATA driver during the installation process.  Your are kidding right?  The proper SATA drivers are used by default.  SATA drives don't need device drivers to function.

Comment: No..  I am not kidding..  I have Dell laptop and have had many issues with SATA - OEM and otherwise.  I know it sounds horribly ridiculous, but have seen funnier things.  To your point, you have to have a SATA driver loaded to see the drive in the first place, so I will give you that.   :)